# Is Signed Request (used in cavas app) and single sign-on are same?

Tags: single-sign-on, canvas

I am very much confused of the type of authentication used to connect a canvas app. If i use Signed Request, would the canvas app still ask me to sign into the app with an username and password? How Signed request and single sign-on are differs?

Thanks,
Baskaran

Comment: You should read more on this thread: http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/23783/how-to-integrate-external-web-app ... basically, the key difference between OAuth and a Signed Request is managing your session. Signed Request does not have an active session, but you can use a token for your app to obtain one in the Salesforce instance where the canvas resides. SR provides a refresh token flow, where OAuth requires a new session each time.

Comment: Thanks @greenstork. I am trying to connect SAP Web dynpro salesorder page as a canvas app in salesforce.